# How to log without logging an error in PHP apache2 docker container?

Tags: php, apache, docker, logging, apache2

I am using this image for [php 7.0.33 apache from docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.0.33-apache-stretch/images/sha256-a69bb3d1833db06a81ff5d85e8e2e0f0105b1596369e061cecac9fe569e0694d?context=explore).

I want to create debug logs so that I see them in the container log (`docker logs my-php-container`) without it being an error.

Trying `apache_note()` (logs nothing) and `error_log('test', null,'/proc/self/fd/1')` (logs as an error) was not successful.
Also using `syslog()` is not an option since this log is not available when running `docker logs`.

Is there some way to actually achieve that?

edit: here is the result of my tests [image: log testing results]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create a logfile in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898688/how-to-create-a-logfile-in-php)

Comment: Have you tried `syslog()`? It will write your logs directly to `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @elliottregan I added a picture containing the results of my tests - I hope this clears up the question.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann I tried - see picture attached, sadly this was not the solution.